# Woocommerce Shortcode 3 Column Not Spanning Full Width

Tags: layout, woocommerce, shortcode

I used the Woocommerce recent products shortcode on [this](http://www.lostgrok.com/new/) page, but it will not span the full width of the page like my [others](http://www.lostgrok.com/product-category/food-stuff/). If there are four columns like they are [here](http://www.lostgrok.com/), then it will work, but I would like three columns.

Does anyone know how to make [this](http://www.lostgrok.com/new/) page's 3 column layout look like this [one](http://www.lostgrok.com/product-category/food-stuff/)?? Thank you!

Here is the shortcode I use:

```
[recent_products per_page="25" columns="3" orderby="date" order="desc" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty right hand sidebar set to the page. You need to change this from the administration panel, most themes have an option to disable the sidebar on this page.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because when I use 4 columns, the page will look like [this](http://lostgrok.com), spanned across the whole page. Just doesn't do it with 3 columns.